# Unity, управление персонажем мышью

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моей игре персонаж управляется мышкой, **wantedpos** берет координаты курсора игрока.
Если условие **if** (27 строчка) выполняется, то внутри этой области персонаж перемещается. При выходе курсора из этой области персонаж абсолютно перестает двигаться. Мне нужно, чтобы, например, персонаж мог перемещаться только по X, если он вышел за допустимую область Y, и наоборот. Попробовал это реализоть в строчках 31 и 35, но безуспешно.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{ 

        Vector3 mousepos = Input.mousePosition;
        var oldX = rb.position.x;
        var oldY = rb.position.y;

        Vector3 wantedpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousepos.x, mousepos.y, 10));

        Vector3 posY = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(oldX, mousepos.y, 10));
        Vector3 posX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousepos.x, oldY, 10));

        if (wantedpos.x >= borderX1 && wantedpos.x <= borderX2 && wantedpos.y >= -borderY && wantedpos.y <= borderY) // Моя игровая зона (27)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(wantedpos);
        }
        if (wantedpos.x < borderX1 && wantedpos.x > borderX2) // Недопустимая зона по X, меняется только Y (31)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(posX);
        }
        if (wantedpos.y < -borderY && wantedpos.y > borderY) // Недопустимая зона по Y, меняется только X (35)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(posY);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ограничить координату можно с помощью [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html):

```
private Vector3 oldMousePos; // для оптимизации

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    if (mousePos == oldMousePos) // не делать лишних движений, если ничего не поменялось
        return;

    Vector3 wantedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 10));

    wantedPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(wantedPos.x, borderX1, borderX2);
    wantedPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(wantedPos.y, -borderY, borderY);

    rb.MovePosition(wantedPos);
    oldMousePos = mousePos;
}
```